# Using ArnLike in conditional when creating resource policy for Secrets Manager does not seem to work

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I am attaching the following resource policy to an SM secret

```json
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Id" : "AllowAccessToSecretValue",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "AllowLambdaAccess",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "Service" : "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret" ],
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:my-secret-xkxkxk",
    "Condition" : {
      "ArnLike" : {
        "aws:SourceArn" : "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:foo*"
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Then I am trying to access it from a `lambda` that has the following code:

```py
secret_name = "my-secret"

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Calling SecretsManager
    get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
        SecretId=secret_name
    )
    
    #Raw Response
    #Extracting the key/value from the secret
    secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    print(secret)
    
    put_secret_value_response = client.update_secret(
            SecretId=secret_name,
            SecretString='fofo'
        )
    secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
    print(secret)
```

The arn of the function is

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:foo-lala
```

The execution fails:

```
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: User: arn:aws:sts::123456789:assumed-role/my-secret/foo-lala is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: my-secret because no identity-based policy allows the secretsmanager:GetSecretValue action",
```

Why is that?

**update**

Removing the `Condition` clause entirely does not seem to work either

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Id" : "AllowAccessToSecretValue",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "AllowLambdaAccess",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "Service" : "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret" ],
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try using the exact ARN to the lambda function, in the condition comparison for `aws:SourceArn` , `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789:function:foo-lala`, Or, change the condition to use a `StringLike`. And also confirm if the assumed role does indeed have the permission to use `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue`.

Comment: Neither the exact `arn` nor the `StringLike` worked. How can I check the permissions of the assumed role?

Comment: As per my question update, the removal of the condition did not work either...

Answer (score 1):

Resource is `"arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:my-secret-xkxkxk"` but you are trying to access `my-secret`!

---

**Update:**

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Id" : "AllowAccessToSecretValue",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Sid" : "AllowLambdaAccess",
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
      "AWS" : "arn:aws:iam::359524702761:role/service-role/foo-lala-role-16s42m8h"
    },
    "Action" : [ "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue", "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret" ],
    "Resource" : "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:359524702761:secret:my-secret-dNl6kV"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue since the `arn` of the secret has a `hex` suffix (the one I am posting)

Comment: Update my answer with policy. I have tested with this policy it work for me.
Principal AWS is lambda role.

Answer (score 0):

Your [resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_resource-policies.html) fails to grant the expected privileges because the Lambda service is not the caller. Rather, the Lambda service assumes the Lambda's execution role and the *role* makes the call to Secrets Manager.

Set the Lambda role as the Principal and remove the condition:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "AllowAccessToSecretValue",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowLambdaAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam:us-east-1:123456789:role/MyLambdaRole"
      },
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:my-secret-xkxkxk"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can match multiple roles with a pattern. Use the "Any" Principal with an `ArnLike` Condition with a wildcard pattern on `aws:PrincipalArn`. This will match whatever role names match the pattern.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "AllowAccessToSecretValue",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowLambdaAccess",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": { "AWS": "*" },
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "secretsmanager:UpdateSecret"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:123456789:secret:my-secret-xkxkxk",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": "arn:aws:iam:us-east-1:123456789:role/*RolePattern*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This will indeed work but I need a solution that uses a pattern for the `lambda`s `arn`

Comment: @pkaramol You can use a pattern for the Lambda's \*role\* ARN.  But not the Lambda's ARN.  The Lambda's ARN is not passed in the call to Secrets Manager.

Comment: For reasons beyond the scope of this question, this role will also be assumed by another service (`ec2.amazonaws.com`). So I wanted to limit this resource to be accessed only by the `lambda.amazonaws.com`. Is this feasible?

Comment: @pkaramol No, I don't believe Secrets Manager knows what goes on the upstream of the Role.  My credence is strengthened by the fact that the `GetSecretValue` logs in CloudTrail don't identify the Lambda service in the caller identity info.

Comment: I'm sure you've already considered identity-based permissions on each Lambda.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I cannot use identity permissions. [This](https://ibb.co/d6jZQT4) however for some strange reason does not work either. [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/auth-and-access_examples.html)

Comment: @pkaramol Some other AWS services may very well call Secrets Manager directly, without assuming a Role.  In which case the linked formulation would seem to work.  Just not with the Lambda service.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is a list with such associations? (which service is allow what other service without role assumption?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250876/discussion-between-fedonev-and-pkaramol).